# reading multiple csv files in R

Tags: r, csv

I want to read multiple files in R

the file location(and name) being:

```
"C:/Users/rohit.gupta/Desktop/Data For Rohit/PacketDetails/DUMP_DATA_PktLevel_1.csv"
"C:/Users/rohit.gupta/Desktop/Data For Rohit/PacketDetails/DUMP_DATA_PktLevel_2.csv"
"C:/Users/rohit.gupta/Desktop/Data For Rohit/PacketDetails/DUMP_DATA_PktLevel_3.csv"
```

till `DUMP_DATA_PktLevel_100.csv`

How can this be done??

Comment: What did you try? What research did you do? Since you are new here, you might want to read the [**about**](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and [**FAQ**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) sections of the website to help you get the most out of it. Please also read [**how to make a great reproducible example**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1478381) and update your question accordingly!

Answer (score 11):

If your csv files are all the .csv files found in your directory you can modify the answer of @Jilber by using the `list.files()` function as such:

```
fileList <- list.files(path="C:/Users/rohit.gupta/Desktop/Data For Rohit/PacketDetails", pattern=".csv")
sapply(fileList, read.csv)
```

You can also limit the files selected by `list.files()` using regular expression, see `?regex`.

Comment: I often use the full.name=TRUE with list.files to get the complete path

Answer (score 6):

Something like this can be useful

```
sapply(paste("C:/Users/rohit.gupta/Desktop/Data For Rohit/
             PacketDetails/DUMP_DATA_PktLevel_", 
             1:100, sep=".csv"), 
       read.csv)
```

Note that if your .csv files have headers, specific type delimiters and other features you can control them by setting the correct arguments in `read.csv` inside `sapply` call, as in:

```
sapply(paste("C:/Users/rohit.gupta/Desktop/Data For Rohit/
                 PacketDetails/DUMP_DATA_PktLevel_", 
                 1:100, sep=".csv"), 
           read.csv, header=TRUE,  dec = ".") # etc
```