# Read from a list of csv filenames into R

Tags: r, list, csv, indexing

I am looking into importing multiple csv files in R

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
for (i in 1:length(temp)) assign(temp[i], read.csv(temp[i]))
```

however

```
temp[1] returns "something.csv"
.......
```

is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655431/reading-multiple-csv-files-in-r or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807945/consolidating-data-frames-in-r or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23169645/r-3-0-3-rbind-multiple-csv-files/23170007#23170007 for a way

Comment: Or perhaps your understanding of `assign`. Try `ls()` and see what is in your workspace...

Comment: Thanks, is there a reason that `head(tables[1])` doesn't return the head but the whole list? and `nrow(tables[1]) = null` for the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807945/consolidating-data-frames-in-r

Comment: You are assigning the output of `read.csv` to the variable named by the string contained in `temp[i]`, i.e. you are assigning it to the variable whose name is `something.csv` so look for `something.csv` and that should contain the result of the read.

Comment: @ G. Grothendieck but `"something.csv"` is a string?

Comment: Following what G.Grothendieck writes: perhaps rename your .csv files prior to assigning the name of the file. See http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Reading-a-bunch-of-csv-files-into-R-td4631383.html

Comment: @xbd; what 'tables'?. But if it is in alist try head(tables[[1]]) - note the double `[`

Comment: Example: `assign( "something.csv" , 1 ); something.csv`

Comment: See solution in my answer. You don't want `assign`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read multiple CSV files into separate data frames](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319839/read-multiple-csv-files-into-separate-data-frames)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLUTION:

Fixes: 1) must use double-[[]] to get the individual list element 2) don't use `assign()`

So either:

```
for (i in 1:length(temp)) { temp[[i]] <- read.csv(temp[i]) }
```

or, if you don't want to overwrite the temp variable:

```
df = c(rep(data.frame(), length(temp))) # list of empty dataframe
for (i in 1:length(temp)) { df[[i]] <- as.list(read.csv(temp[i])) }
```

There were two separate mistakes in your original code:

1. using single [] instead of double [[]]. Single [] gives you a ***list slice containing one element*** (not what you want to assign to), instead of ***just that actual element***.
2. `assign` is not doing what you think it's doing, as @G-Grothendieck said.

You simply want to do `temp[[i]] <- read.csv(temp[i])`

But what you're actually doing is assigning to ***the variable whose name is contained in temp[i]***. So if temp[i] is *'whosyour.csv'*, you're actually creating and assigning to a variable with that name, rather than assigning to temp[i] itself:

```
whosyour.csv <- read.csv('whosyour.csv') # NOT WHAT YOU WANTED!
```

Answer (score 4):

No need for `for` looping in R when we have `sapply` (and the other `*apply` functions).

In this case, with no further arguments `sapply` returns a named list of data frames, which I will call `read.all`.

```
> temp <- list.files(pattern = "*.csv")
> read.all <- sapply(temp, read.csv)
```

Looking at `read.all` shows that it is a **named** list of data frames.

You can then access the individual data frames by file name with

```
> read.all[["filename.csv"]]  ## or read.all["filename.csv"]
```

or with the `$` operator

```
> read.all$filename.csv
```

Comment: However OP wants to do it, it's useful to know you need `[[i]]` indexing when you access `temp`.

Comment: Unless you enjoy getting failures like *In addition: Warning message:
In temp[i] <- read.csv(temp[i]) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length*

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
temp <- list.files(pattern = "*.csv")
## for individual files
dataset <- lapply(temp,FUN=function(files){read.table(files,header=TRUE, sep=",")})
dataset[1] ## for specific files of interest, OR
## If your CSV column structure is same across all csv's bind them all into 1 file
dataset <- do.call("rbind",lapply(temp,FUN=function(files){read.table(files,header=TRUE, sep=",")}))
```