# How to loop to read one file after another in R?

Tags: r, loops

My files are systemically named and all in the same folder. So I want to take advantage and write a function to read them one by one instead of doing this manually for each one.

The names are stored in this text file:

```
DF <- read.table(text="       site                column row
1          abs   1259 463
2         adm   1253 460
3        afrm   1258 463", header=T)
```

I want to write a function to go row by row  and do this:

```
You can see for instance if we apply for the first row:
```

`cor$site`  is  `abs`  so:

```
   file1=read.table("C:\\Data\\abs.txt",sep = "\t")
```

`cor$column`  is `1259`

`cor$row`     is `463`

So

```
 wf= read.table("C:\\Users\\measurement_ 1259_463.txt", sep =' ' , header =TRUE)
```

Now I do any calculations with `file1` and `wf`.........

And then go to the second row and so on.

Comment: `?file.path()` and `?paste()` might be useful here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [reading multiple csv files in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655431/reading-multiple-csv-files-in-r)

Comment: possible duplicate of [consolidating data frames in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807945/consolidating-data-frames-in-r)

Comment: It is not a complete duplicate of the other questions since it also involves some string pasting. I chose to retract my vote for closing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a character vector with the file names you want to read and follow the instructions in [consolidating data frames in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807945/consolidating-data-frames-in-r) or [reading multiple csv files in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655431/reading-multiple-csv-files-in-r).

```
files <- data.frame(
    site = paste("C:\\Data\\", DF$site, ".txt", sep=""),
    measurement = paste("C:\\Users\\measurement_", DF$column, "_",
                        DF$row, ".txt", sep=""),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

results <- Map(function(s, m){
    file1 <- read.table(s, sep="\t")
    wt <- read.table(m, sep=' ', header=TRUE)
    # Do stuff
    return(result)
}, files$site, files$measurement)

# Alternatively
results <- vector("list", nrow(files))
for(i in 1:nrow(files)){
    file1 <- read.table(files$site[i], sep="\t")
    wt <- read.table(files$measurment[i], sep=' ', header=TRUE)
    # Do stuff
    results[[i]] <- # result
}
```

Comment: Put whatever you want to do in the function you send to lapply or do a `for`, but that is a less  R:ish solution.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't catch all the details the first time. What about this then?

Comment: Just type `result` and you get all of it, or `unlist(result)` to flatten it to a vector. If the result is just a single number each time you can change `Map` to `mapply` or `results <- rep(NA, nrow(files))` before the for loop.

Comment: Ah sorry, forgot to add the `stringsAsFactors` to the `data.frame` call.